# I need to have the user input a list of 16-bit integers and then push them into a stack, then pop them out in order to display reverse

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I need to have the user input a list of 16-bit integers and then push them into a stack, then pop them out in order to display them in reverse order i.e 15,16,82is inputted it should display 82,16,15 Currently it is just displaying 28,61,51. What is the problem ?

```
.model SMALL
.stack
.data
string DB 50 DUP('$'),0dh,0ah,"$"
prompt DB "Enter any numbers of your choice(Max 16 numbers): ",0dh,0ah,"$"
.code

mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
;display prompt message
lea dx,prompt
mov ah,09h
int 21h
;read string from the user
lea si,string
mov cx,16
mov ah,1
next:
int 21h
cmp al,0dh
je doneread
mov [si],al
inc si
loop next
doneread:

mov dl,0ah
mov ah,2
int 21h

call reverse ;call reverse function

mov dl,0ah
mov ah,2
int 21h

mov dl,0dh
mov ah,2
int 21h

lea dx,string

mov ah,09h ; Output the string
int 21h ; loaded in in DX

; Interrupt to exit
mov ah,4ch
int 21h

;////////////////////////////////////////////////////
; reverse PROC

reverse PROC ; Load the offset of the string
mov si,offset string ; lea si, string
mov cx,0h ; count of the character of the string

loop1:
mov ax,[si]
CMP al,'$' ; compare if it is the end of the string or not
JE label1

; If not equal then:
push [si]
inc si ; Next Character check
inc cx ; counter of the characters
JMP loop1 ; Continue to the other characters

label1:
mov si,offset string


loop2:
CMP cx,0
JE exit

; if not equal then:
pop dx ; popping the top of the stack
xor dh,dh ; clearing the value of dh (0000h)
mov [si],dx ; put the reversed character in the [si] offset
inc si
dec cx

JMP loop2

exit:

mov [si],'$'
RET

reverse ENDP

ret
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  It helps if you [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) code in your post using code blocks, and assembly language questions should use a tag for the architecture in question.  I've added these to your post.

Comment: Are you pushing each digit separately, so you're reversing the digits in each number?  Does your assignment tell you that you have to convert each input to a binary integer?  If not, you could just store strings in memory and push pointers.